# MonoTouch and IDisposable Pattern

Tags: .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, idisposable

Reading MT documentation, I've seen that it is possible to release memory also implementing the IDisposable .NET pattern.

For example, in a custom class that extends UIViewController (MyViewController), I could override the following method:

```
public override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
   if (disposing){
     // do some stuff here
   }
   base.Dispose (disposing)
}
```

Starting from this point, my two questions are:

1. What type of elements do I have to release in addition to images?
2. Do I have to call the Dispose method from an instance of MyViewController class (myViewController.Dispose()) or the Dispose method is called automatically like dealloc method?

Thank you in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First MonoTouch usage of [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) is identical to Mono or .NET. What you read about this subject elsewhere, on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface) or on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx)... will all apply here.

What's important wrt MonoTouch is to remember that `NSObject` implements `IDisposable` which makes a lot of sense since it represent a native object. That means that everything that inherits from `NSObject`, quite a large part of **monotouch.dll**, implements `IDisposable`.

> 1. What type of elements do I have to release in addition to images?

Most **managed** NSObject-based object instances are small but they can represent large **native** objects (the **GC** will only know about the first, managed, size).

So it's best to Dispose NSObject-based instances when you can, e.g. when you're using them as local variables. The `using` pattern makes it easy to do so in C#.

OTOH use your judgment, a small `NSString` won't take much memory, while others could be large (or unknown, e.g. `NSString GetWebPageContent (NSUrl)`.

> 2. Do I have to call the Dispose method from an instance of MyViewController class (myViewController.Dispose()) or the Dispose method is called automatically like dealloc method?

Part of the `Dispose` pattern ensure that the **finalizer** will call `Dispose` if it has not been called previously. As such the **GC** will, eventually, reclaim the memory (both managed and unmanaged/native) associated with those instances.

You might want to use some tools, like [Gendarme](https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/wiki) (which will run on OSX) or FxCop (Windows-only) that will report to you (for example) if some of your types have IDisposable fields that are not disposed properly.

*Disclaimer* : I'm Gendarme's maintainer :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Very helpful. The only thing I didn't understand is the following: "Most managed NSObject-based object instances are small but they can represent large native objects (the GC will only know about the first, managed, size)." Could you explain what does it mean? Thank you again.

Comment: From _StackOverflow iDisposable Tag info_ it's clear the difference between managed and unmanaged objects: unmanaged ones are outside of the reach of the .NET garbage collector. In MT I haven't so clear the difference between the two and I have difficulties to apply the correct memory management behaviour.

Comment: Things like `new NSString ("a")` and `new NSString ("aaa...1000...aaa")` are, from a managed point of view, the same size - i.e. the sizeof(NSString) which is mostly just an handle, `IntPtr` that points to the native NSString object. As such the GC cannot use the *real* memory total to decide when to collect. However once the second is collected, `Dispose` will be called, and the long string will be freed. That's where some judgment when using (or not) `Dispose` inside your code can help you conserve memory (by ensuring it's released as-soon-as-possible).

Comment: That means I should use using() if dealing with NS* objects directly. But does this also apply if I use a managed Monotouch object that internally uses NS*?

Comment: A large part of monotouch.dll is generated by tools (btouch) and this ensure that Dispose is called when required (i.e. you don't have to worry about the internals of MonoTouch). However if an object contain `IDisposable` fields then it's a great *candidate* to implement `IDisposable` itself (Gendarme warns for this too). Judgment about when and how those types are used also applies (about implementing `IDisposable` and disposing manually the instances) - but it's never a *mistake* to do it (as long as th object is not required anymore, anywhere!)